# Node.js WebSockets - send data to server with BasicAuth

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, basic-authentication

I am using the Node.js WebSockets (require("ws")) to create a client and server. I also have express app that is running the server and is using Basic Authentication:

```
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let expressWs = require('express-ws');
expressWs(app);    
let auth = require('basic-auth');

let server = app.listen(8080);
app.use(auth);
```

Now I am creating a client websocket and I am trying to connect to the server websocket:

```
let WebSocket = require('ws');
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8080/");
```

Using the prefix user:pass I managed to make a connection to the server. But now I cannot send a message...

```
ws.onopen = function () {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({type: "available", user: "user"}));
}
```

From all that I read I reckon I have to send some headers with the message, but I don't know how. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you using [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) as it simplifies the usage of WS. This is how the basic auth could be done using Socket.IO:

**Client side**:

---

```
    <script src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io('127.0.0.1:8080', function() {
         transports: ['websocket']
         query: 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password)
      });
      socket.on('connect', function() {
         // You will get here only if next() is passed with an empty body
         socket.emit('msg', { type: "available", user: "user" });
      });
    </script>
```

---

**Server side**:

---

```
this.io = require('socket.io').listen('8080');
this.io.use(function(socket, next) {
   // Getting auth data
   // 'request' contains the 'username' and 'password' variables you passed
   // from the client side
   var authData = socket.handshake.query
   //  Use authData to check if access granted for this user
   var accessGranted = this.checkAccess(authData);
   if (accessGranted) {
     // next() call will grant the connection between server and client
     next();
  }
});
```

For more info, please refer to the link I provided above.

### EDIT

---

I finally managed to find this out. This line `app.use(auth);` is causing the problem. Remove it and you'll be fine.

If you want to use the basic-auth, use it **inside** `app.ws('/', function (ws, req) {});` to check whether or not this user is authorized. Here's the basic-auth [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth). Hope you'll work this out!

Comment: I must use express-ws on the server side. Will this work if I do only the client as socket.IO?

Comment: Yes, it only works with Socket.IO. I will try to provide an example with express-ws.

Comment: How do you check that your server has allowed the connection to the client? Try to send some sample message from the server on connect. You can then check it on the client with this function `ws.onmessage()`

Comment: I manage to get a response from the server in the ws.onmessage handler. Also the ws.onopen handler manages to print a line when the connection is open. But when I send a message from the client to the server, no message arrives.

Comment: What is your 'onmessage' listener on the server side looks like?

Comment: app.ws('/', function (ws, req) {
    console.log("new connection");
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({msg: "connected"}));
    ws.isAlive = true;
    ws.on('message', function (message) {
        let msg = JSON.parse(message);
        console.log("server", msg);

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(message)` before `JSON.parse(message)` to check if it's simply getting there?

Comment: Yeah, it is not.

Comment: One more question: are you getting inside `ws.onopen()`?

Comment: Yes, I am getting.

Comment: @BozhidarGanev Did you try what I described in the **EDIT** section above?

Comment: Ok, I will upvote your answer because I think it may actually solve the problem. However, as a requirement I must do normal HTTP requests to the app (not to the socket) that must use basic auth, so in my case I will need to use something else. But thanks for your help!

Comment: If you don't need ws, just use basic-auth by itself. There's a great example in the doc I posted earlier. I'm glad I could help you! Good luck!